# How to compare Time in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

I need to use a Time object as a int (TimeObject.to_i)
Then i need to convert a int back to a Time, to compare against the original Time.
Short Example

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.at(t1.to_i)
puts t1 == t2    # Says False
puts t1.eql?(t2) # Says False
```

Why this says its false ? 
When i print both Time objetcs shows the same thing D:

```
puts t1                 #shows : 2012-01-06 16:01:53 -0300
puts t2                 #shows : 2012-01-06 16:01:53 -0300
puts t1.to_a.to_s       #shows : [ 53, 1, 16, 6, 1, 2012, 5, 6, true, "CLST"]      
puts t2.to_a.to_s       #shows : [ 53, 1, 16, 6, 1, 2012, 5, 6, true, "CLST"]
```

they are the same thing D: but when trying to compare with == or eql? says they are diferent
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Answer

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.at(t1.to_i)
t3 = Time.at(t1.to_i)
puts t1  # 2012-01-06 23:09:41 +0400
puts t2  # 2012-01-06 23:09:41 +0400
puts t3  # 2012-01-06 23:09:41 +0400

puts t1 == t2      # false
puts t1.equal?(t2) # false
puts t1.eql?(t2)   # false

puts t2.equal? t3  # false
puts t2.eql? t3    # true
puts t2 == t3      # true
```

Explanation:

> #### eql?(other_time)
>
> Return true if time and other_time are both Time objects with the same seconds and fractional seconds.

Link: [Time#eql?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-eql-3F)

So, apparently, fractions of seconds get dropped when performing `#to_i` and then restored time is not exactly the same as original one. But if we restore two copies, they will be equal.

One may think, "Hey, let's use `#to_f` then!". But, surprisingly enough, results are the same! Maybe it's because of rounding errors or floating point comparison, not sure.

#### Alternate answer

Don't convert integer back to time for comparison. Convert original time to int instead!

```
t1 = Time.now
t2 = Time.at(t1.to_i)

puts t1  # 2012-01-06 23:44:06 +0400
puts t2  # 2012-01-06 23:44:06 +0400

t1int, t2int = t1.to_i, t2.to_i

puts t1int == t2int           # true
puts t1int.equal?(t2int.to_i) # true
puts t1int.eql?(t2int)        # true
```

Comment: For the fourth test that says `t1 == t1`, did you mean to put `t1 == t2`? Otherwise your results reflect what the OP is saying.

Comment: It would be better to use `to_f` on the `Time` objects instead; `to_f` keeps the fractional seconds.  One other thing to note, it would be unwise to compare tiny fractions of a second if the Time objects were obtained using different time sources.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, results are the same, `t1 != t2`. :puzzled:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I completely agree.  I would do t1.to_f == t2.to_f since that ensures numerical comparison between them.  The underlying C code compares the time in seconds and then the microseconds.

Comment: @Nick: it's better not to compare floating point numbers like this. It's advised to compare with epsilon (`t1.to_f is_within(0.0001).of(t2.to_f)`). I am not sure if this advice still holds for Ruby (since it has 'native' big numbers and all that), but it's true for languages like C.

Comment: seconds (32 bits) + microseconds (20 bits or so) sounds like it would be right at the limit of the precision you get from a Float

Comment: damn i posted this question as a ruby newby D: didnt except that king of explanation ;D im scared of ruby now, thank you for helping anyway :d

Comment: @RobinsonHernandez: Ruby is a magical language, invest in learning it and it will pay back :-)