# Rails on date object values returned by date.end_of_day.to_datetime and date.to_datetime.end_of_day when compared returns false

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activesupport

**ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]**

**Rails 3.0.20**

Recently why working on a project on RSpecs related to DateTime on Rails I found out that 
*on a given date* the values emitted by following statements

```
    date.end_of_day.to_datetime
```

and

```
    date.to_datetime.end_of_day
```

when compared returned false though they represented identical date-time.

To confirm this I opened up Rails console and tried out following

```
  1.9.3dev :053 > monday = Time.now.monday
   => 2013-02-25 00:00:00 +0530

  1.9.3dev :054 > monday.class
   => Time

  1.9.3dev :055 > d1 = monday + 1.hour
   => 2013-02-25 01:00:00 +0530

  1.9.3dev :056 > d2 = monday + 1.hour
   => 2013-02-25 01:00:00 +0530

  1.9.3dev :058 > d1_eod_datetime = d1.end_of_day.to_datetime
   => Mon, 25 Feb 2013 23:59:59 +0530

  1.9.3dev :059 > d2_eod_datetime = d2.to_datetime.end_of_day
   => Mon, 25 Feb 2013 23:59:59 +0530

  1.9.3dev :061 > d1_eod_datetime == d2_eod_datetime
   => false

  1.9.3dev :062 > d3_eod_datetime = d2.to_datetime.end_of_day
   => Mon, 25 Feb 2013 23:59:59 +0530

  1.9.3dev :063 > d2_eod_datetime == d3_eod_datetime
   => true
```

and it seems my observation looks correct.That is:

When **d1_eod_datetime and d2_eod_datetime** are compared it **returns false**

When **d2_eod_datetime and d3_eod_datetime** are compared it **returns true**

It looks like an inconsistent behavior to me, however would appreciate if
anybody can make me understand what is going on behind the scenes and why the
comparisons made on values using **date.end_of_day.to_datetime** and
**date.to_datetime.end_of_day** fails though the source **date** object represents identical date-time.

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763050/how-to-compare-time-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

Although their string representations are the same, `d1_eod_datetime` doesn't equal `d2_eod_datetime`. They differ in their least significant bits. If you convert your datetimes to a float representation, you can see that they're not equal:

```
d1_eod_datetime.to_f
=> 1381788000.0
d2_eod_datetime.to_f
=> 1381787999.0
```

The problem occurs when the `Time` instance receives the `end_of_day` message. Passing the `end_of_day` message to the `Time` instance returns a `DateTime` instance. The conversion to `DateTime` might result in a loss of accuracy and the new `DateTime` instance might not exactly equal to your original `Time` instance.